# Django: If model field has editable=False does it matter if blank is set to True or False?

Tags: django, django-models

From Django:

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

> Field.editable
>   If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is True.

> Field.blank
>   If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.?
>
> Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

Am I correct when I say `blank=True` won't be validated? Does it matter in this case if it was set to `blank=False`?

Comment: `blank=True` will be validated as long it is not empty. For example let's say you have an `INTEGER` field and you allow it to be `NULL` (`null=True`), the HTML field may be empty and the validation won't bother you but if you input `hello world` in the HTML field, the validation will fail as `hello world` is not an integer.

Comment: editable is only related to the admin interface, blank is checked everywhere. Nobody prevents you to edit the value inside your application, it's pure convenience to prevent the admin from action, which possibly break the integrity of your application (not the db, but your own logic) by disallowing editing the field.